# Varnish cache installation failed

Tags: varnish

I am trying to run varnish but I get this error:

Backend host "myapp.app": resolves to multiple IPv4 addresses.
Only one address is allowed.
Please specify which exact address you want to use, we found these:
     192.168.10.10
     192.168.10.10

If anyone could give me a suggestion on how to resolve this.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have multiple entries for "myapp.app" in your local `hosts` file or in your local DNS-server. Varnish doesn't support that.

Check your `hosts` file by

```
cat /etc/hosts
```

And remove any duplicates of myapp.app. If the hostname resolves to a DNS-server you have to adjust the entries there so myapp.app only points to 1 ip-address.